# in a graphql schema directive, is there any way to check if the expected return field is non-nullable

Tags: graphql, apollo

I have a schema directive that does a db query and returns the expected result. Some fields where I use this directive are non-nullable. Which means in the case where there's bad user input like the client asking for some data that doesn't exist, the client will get a "Can't return null for non nullable field" general exception. While this is ok, it would be better if I could throw a UserInputError

When I'm doing this in resolvers, since I know what the field is, I simply check if the return value is null and throw new UserInputError. In the directive I don't know if the field is nullable though, so I don't know when to return null or throw. Is there a way to check?

here's the code:

```
export class QueryDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field;
    const directiveArgs = { ...this.args };
    field.resolve = async function(obj, args, context, info) {
      const session = context.driver.session();
      let queryResult = await session.run(directiveArgs.statement, args);
      session.close();
      let result = extractResult(result, "result");
      // Any way to check here if field is non-nullable and throw new UserInputError?
      if (!directiveArgs.resolve) return resolve.call(this, result, args, context, info);
      else return result;
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `field` object passed to `visitFieldDefinition` is of the type `GraphField`:

```
export interface GraphQLField<
  TSource,
  TContext,
  TArgs = { [key: string]: any }
> {
  name: string;
  description: Maybe<string>;
  type: GraphQLOutputType;
  args: GraphQLArgument[];
  resolve?: GraphQLFieldResolver<TSource, TContext, TArgs>;
  subscribe?: GraphQLFieldResolver<TSource, TContext, TArgs>;
  isDeprecated?: boolean;
  deprecationReason?: Maybe<string>;
  extensions: Maybe<Readonly<Record<string, any>>>;
  astNode?: Maybe<FieldDefinitionNode>;
}
```

So you can determine the field's type by accessing `field.type`. Non-null is a wrapper type. If a field is non-null, `field.type` will return a `GraphQLNonNull` object with a `ofType` property referencing the wrapped type.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, this pointed me to the right place, field.type returns the actual type name, but I found "NonNullType" in field.astNode.type.kind.

Comment: `field.type` will be an object, not just a string, though it may appear to be a string if you're just logging it with `console.log`. But yes, you can parse the `astNode` too to get the same information.

Comment: got it, that's exactly why I thought it was a string. Thanks again!